# Labels in diagram too far from lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, labels

I'm having trouble with the labels in my diagram.  I want them closer to the lines, but I can't seem to find a way.  Is there any way to put the labels closer to the lines?

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto, minimum width = 3em, minimum height = 3em,
  thick, main node/.style={rectangle,fill=white,draw}
 ]

  \node[main node,node distance=3cm] (2) {I(t)};
  \node[main node,node distance=3cm] (1) [left of=2] {S(t)};
  \node[main node,node distance=3cm] (3) [right of=2] {A(t)};
  \node[below of=1,node distance=2cm] (dummy1) {};
  \node[below of=2,node distance=2cm] (dummy2) {};
  \node[below of=3,node distance=2cm] (dummy3) {};
  \node[right of=3,node distance=2cm] (dummy4) {};
  \node[left of=1,node distance=2cm] (dummy) {};


 \draw[->,draw=black] (1)  -- node {$\lambda(t)$} (2);
 \draw[->,draw=black] (2)  -- node {$\alpha$} (3);
 \draw[->,draw=black] (dummy) -- node {$\Lambda$} (1);
 \draw[->,draw=black] (1) -- node {$\mu$} (dummy1);
 \draw[->,draw=black] (2) -- node {$\mu$} (dummy2);
 \draw[->,draw=black] (3) -- node {$\mu$} (dummy3);
 \draw[->,draw=black] (3) -- node {$\nu$} (dummy4);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have set a **node size** with a minimum of `3em`s in both width and height within the whole `tikzpicture` environment while this should only be associated with the `main node/.style`. Here is what I mean:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,
  thick, main node/.style={rectangle,fill=white,draw, minimum width = 3em, minimum height = 3em}
 ]

  \node[main node,node distance=3cm] (2) {I(t)};
  \node[main node,node distance=3cm] (1) [left of=2] {S(t)};
  \node[main node,node distance=3cm] (3) [right of=2] {A(t)};
  \node[below of=1,node distance=2cm] (dummy1) {};
  \node[below of=2,node distance=2cm] (dummy2) {};
  \node[below of=3,node distance=2cm] (dummy3) {};
  \node[right of=3,node distance=2cm] (dummy4) {};
  \node[left of=1,node distance=2cm] (dummy) {};


 \draw[->,draw=black] (1)  -- node [outer ysep=0pt]{$\lambda(t)$} (2);
 \draw[->,draw=black] (2)  -- node {$\alpha$} (3);
 \draw[->,draw=black] (dummy) -- node {$\Lambda$} (1);
 \draw[->,draw=black] (1) -- node {$\mu$} (dummy1);
 \draw[->,draw=black] (2) -- node {$\mu$} (dummy2);
 \draw[->,draw=black] (3) -- node {$\mu$} (dummy3);
 \draw[->,draw=black] (3) -- node {$\nu$} (dummy4);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

With the expected output:

[image]

Comment: `node distance` is not global here. It is local to the paths.

Comment: I mean global to the `tikzpicture` environment not to a specific path.

Comment: I mean there is no `node distance` set globally. But that's what you are saying at the first sentence.

Comment: I edited this to prevent any confusion. Thanks for the notion.

Comment: It is not actually related to node distance. See my answer. node distance sets the distance between nodes. Here it is the node that is big.

Answer (score 4):

If you put this line between two blocks of code

```
\tikzset{every node/.style={draw}}
```

this is what you would see

[image]

You can see that all of them have extra spacing around the math text inside them. This is because the tikzpicture options you have provided `minimum width = 3em, minimum height = 3em` applies to everything unless you override them.

One option is as AboAmmar showed, take them into the `mainnode` style or use

```
\tikzset{every node/.style={minimum size=0pt}}
```

to reset the options after the first chunk of code..